# How can I merge the two heads in Hg now?

Tags: mercurial, merge

I read many posts already, and it seems like none can help.

```
yeukhon@glasslab:~/hg/graphyte-webclient/webclient/apps$ hg merge
merging .hgignore
merging webclient/codebundle_ldap.log
warning: conflicts during merge.
merging webclient/codebundle_ldap.log failed!
merging webclient/codebundle_lib.log
warning: conflicts during merge.
merging webclient/codebundle_lib.log failed!
merging webclient/graphyte_lib.log
warning: conflicts during merge.
merging webclient/graphyte_lib.log failed!
merging webclient/profile_models.log
warning: conflicts during merge.
merging webclient/profile_models.log failed!
30 files updated, 1 files merged, 0 files removed, 4 files unresolved
use 'hg resolve' to retry unresolved file merges or 'hg update -C .' to abandon
```

I tried this, which marks each as resolved I think

```
hg resolve -m webclient/profile_models.log 
etc
```

and then update again, but doesn't work. It still tells me

```
abort: outstanding uncommitted merges
```

This is my hg summary

```
yeukhon@glasslab:~/hg/graphyte-webclient/webclient/apps$ hg summary
parent: 106:5082a4f13c33 tip
 merged with yeukhon's repo
parent: 96:0e3cfc289a18 
 Put logs into one directory called logs.
branch: default
commit: 35 modified, 4 unresolved (merge)
update: (current)
```

MY co-worker pushed one and I just pushed another one. How do I deal with this problem?  Thanks.

---

Those logs are no longer needed. In fact, in my push I removed them because I put them in a directory called **`"logs"`**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After resolving the merge, you must do a `commit` before updating again.

Each time you merge, you must commit before doing anything else. So just do `hg commit`, give some meaningful commit message and you will be able to continue your job.